# Android: how get from (setMyLocationEnabled) -> longitude and latitude?

Tags: android, google-maps, location, currentlocation

how I can get latitude and longitude from setMyLocationEnabled? while my code is this.
I need to use it to zoomin to location,

```
    private void setUpMap() {
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0,0)).title("Marker"));
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng());
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(13));
}
```

Comment: You can get a lot of examples from google. Anyways refer here:http://coderzpassion.com/android-location-using-google-play-services/

Answer (score 0):

For getting individual latitude and longitude, the following works for me.

```
 mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        double lat = mMap.getMyLocation().getLatitude();
        double longt = mMap.getMyLocation().getLongitude();
```

Answer (score 0):

Google map location API has the listeners you can get your current location by using this.

```
private GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener myLocationChangeListener = new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
    LatLng loc = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    mMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(loc));
    if(mMap != null){
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(loc, 16.0f));
    }
}
};
```

And then set the listener for the map.

```
mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(myLocationChangeListener);
```

Comment: setOnMyLocationChangeListener method is Deprecated now.
You can use FusedLocationProviderApi instead.